# Login Page Error Code Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory Express.js Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

Well when i want to check the login page after I turn on the server

it gives me error like this

`Error: Failed to lookup view "login" in views directory "C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\src\Tampilan"`

```
at Function.render (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:597:17)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
at _clear (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\req-flash\index.js:18:9)
at login (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\Controllers\login-controller.js:14:13)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at isLogout (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\koneksi\verifikasi.js:14:13)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Monthy Goreng\Documents\Microsoft Visual Studio Code Project\Javascript Project\Aplikasi Website Restoran\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
```

This is the screen capture
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vika7.png)

And my suspect is, the problem is from my login things source code like from my login.ejs, login-controller.js, and login-route.js

and I don't have any idea what part that is the error source of the script from that login things source code, probably you guys can help me (Maybe it would be better if there's any Indonesian programmer that found this questions because some of the things here are related with Bahasa Indonesia)

[login.ejs script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErE60.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="id">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body style="padding: 0px !important;">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <form action="<%= url %>login/auth" method="POST" class="col-md-4 card">
                
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan Username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan Password" required>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                <a href="<%= url %>register" class="btn btn-success">Register</a>
                
                <%if (pesanFlash) { %>
                    <div class="alert alert-<%= colorFlash %> alert-dismissible fade show mt-3" role="alert">
                        <strong><%= statusFlash %></strong> 
                        <%= pesanFlash %>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <% } %>

            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[login-controller.js script 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0lC.png)

[login-controller.js script 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBQUE.png)

```
const config = require('../Koneksi/koneksi');

let mysql = require('mysql');
let pool  = mysql.createPool(config);

pool.on('error',(err)=> {
    console.error(err);
});

module.exports ={

    login(req,res){
        res.render("login",{
            url : 'http://localhost:5050/',

            colorFlash: req.flash('color'),
            statusFlash: req.flash('status'),
            pesanFlash: req.flash('message'),
        });
    },

    loginAuth(req,res){
        let username = req.body.username;
        let password = req.body.pass;
        if (username && password) {
            pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
                if (err) throw err;
                connection.query(
                    `SELECT * FROM table users WHERE username = ? AND password = SHA2(?,512)`
                , [username, password],function (error, results) {
                    if (error) throw error;  
                    if (results.length > 0) {


                        req.session.loggedin = true;
                        req.session.userid = results[0].id_user;
                        req.session.username = results[0].username;
                        res.redirect('/');
                    } else {

                        req.flash('color', 'danger');
                        req.flash('status', 'Oops..');
                        req.flash('message', 'Akun tidak ditemukan');
                        res.redirect('/login');
                    }
                });
                connection.release();
            })
        } else {
            res.redirect('/login');
            res.end();
        }
    },

'http://localhost:5050/login/logout'
    logout(req,res){

        req.session.destroy((err) => {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            res.clearCookie('secretname');
            res.redirect('/login');
        });
    },
}
```

[login-route.js script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8QBg.png)

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const loginController = require('../Controllers').login;
const verifikasiUser = require('../Koneksi/verifikasi');

router.get('/', verifikasiUser.isLogout, loginController.login);
router.get('/logout', loginController.logout);

router.post('/auth', loginController.loginAuth);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please do not link to images of code. Instead, you can copy and paste the relevant functions or blocks of code into the question.

Comment: the code tag is error when I want to share the code with the code tag "```" so I decided to share the image's code

Comment: Show both code and error as text, not an image.